# Unable to get C# server to play nicely with Python client on separate computers on same network

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, networking, wii-balanceboard

Any ideas on why I can't get a unity C# server and python client on the same network to play nicely?

C# server

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

using System.Threading;

using UnityEngine;

public class Wiiboard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int port;

    public void StartClient()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Debug.Log(String.Format("Connected!"));

                data = null;

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Debug.Log(String.Format("Received: {0}", data));

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    // Send back a response.
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    Debug.Log(String.Format("Sent: {0}", data));
                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError(String.Format("SocketException: {0}", e));
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }

        Debug.Log(String.Format("\nHit enter to continue..."));
        Console.Read();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartClient));
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

python client:

```py
HOST = '192.168.0.38'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 25565        # The port used by the server

#https://realpython.com/python-sockets/
def client():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        print(f"CLIENT >>> waiting to connect to {HOST}:{PORT}")
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        s.sendall(b'Hello, world!<EOF>')
        data = s.recv(1024)

    print('CLIENT >>> Received', repr(data))

[other, entirely irrelevant code. just stuff for the wiiboard]

client()
```

For context, I'm trying to relay data from a Wii balance board connected to my laptop(windows wouldn't play nicely with the board and VR doesn't play nicely with Linux as I've heard) to my desktop over a socket connection into unity. I've had no issues with sockets when my laptop was running windows, but since I had to run Linux on the laptop for this, it's stopped playing nicely.

I'm running the python client on my laptop running ubuntu 18.08 LTS and I am running the C# server on my windows 10 desktop in unity.

- I've checked that the IP and port is okay
- I've checked that both unity and the built application have firewall exceptions
- I've ran the python client locally on the desktop and had it work
- I've tried the same python client on the laptop but on windows with the same result

Clearly the code is not at fault here, but that leaves the question, what is?

Comment: In general I would rather use a [`TcpListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener) instead of setting up the socket "by hand" ...

Comment: Have you tried using e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) on your Unity/Server device and check if the connection attempt (or anything) is received from your python device IP at all?

Comment: No chance your windows firewall is on?

Comment: No. I've checked that both unity and the application when built have firewall exceptions, although i could always disable the firewall for testing. I'm going through the other suggestions first, but i'll certainly try it.
Furthermore, when testing the client on windows, it shouldn't block outgoing connections.

Comment: @derHugo I've just done that now. I'm getting some TCP traffic on my desktop from my laptop's IP, but it seemingly never reaches the server

Comment: I should clarify, the traffic reaches my computer, but the server doesn't react in the slightest to it

Comment: @BugFinder I thought i had made sure that i'd made an exception for the application, but that must have only applied to outgoing traffic. I disabled the firewall and it worked first try. Now i need to figure out how to allow the server with the firewall on. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was simply to add a firewall exception using [This helpful resource](http://lexisnexis.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1081611/%7E/adding-exceptions-to-the-windows-firewall)

Comment: I will accept this answer when allowed in two days

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).